# UITableView moves cell contents around when scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have seen other questions on here related to this, but I have their solutions in place, and things still move around when I scroll.

Basically, I have a table of data and I want the first and only the first row to have a UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator.  The problem is, when I scroll around, the indicator duplicates, deletes, and moves to other cells.  Here is my code..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }    

    if(indexPath.row == 0) {      
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;           
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [tabledata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

The problem is something with the indexPath.row variable.. its somehow returning 0 in other cells that aren't the very first (when it comes to displaying cells).  HOWEVER... the data is always right from my array(which implies the value HAS to be correct) and in my

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
```

method, i only wish to change screens when row 0 is clicked.. and regardless of where I have scrolled to, no cells trigger except the very first.  So it seems THAT check is always correct while the one inside cellForRowAtIndexPath is not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you are re-using cells that already have the `accessoryType` set. You need to explicitly set it to NOT show on cells where it shouldn't.

```
if(indexPath.row == 0){      
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;       
} else {
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Comment: Oh wow.. I would of assumed when you re-used the cells all that information is chucked.  It actually retains that?   *edit* that was the issue.  Thanks man.  I would of never figured that was happening.

Comment: It confused me when I first started using UITableview, too. I suppose there is no way for the tableview to know how the cells are supposed to look in their "pristine" condition, so they just give you whatever is cached and let you deal with it!